# CSRF cookie not set при отправке запросов через postman

Tags: python, django

использую для аутентификации django-allauth. Вот мой urls.

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/auth/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

Если отправлять запрос через браузер на адрес

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth/email/
```

то все хорошо, но если отправлять такой же POST-запрос через Postman то я получаю ошибку

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/v1/auth/email/
```

в settings.py нету таких настроек

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE
```

Comment: во вьюшке, которая обрабатывает запрос, есть from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
и
@csrf_exempt перед функцией?

Comment: вот вью это библиотеки https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py, я не нашел @csrf_exempt